# Catch block does not catch exception, why?

Tags: c#, .net

I am coding a rogue-like console program but I have a question:

My code does not catch an exception. I have a `void` with `for` loops and `arrays`.
The error happens when the array is out of range. This happens because the void doesn't check if the array is bellow zero or over the maximum.

```
    void lightUp(int pos)
    {
        //first and second
        for (int i = 1; i > -2; i--)
        {
            int lolPos = pos + (i * columns);
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                tiles[lolPos + j].isVisible = true;
                tiles[lolPos - j].isVisible = true;
            }
        }

        //third
        for (int i = 2; i > -3; i -= 4)
        {
            int lolPos = pos + (i * columns);
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
                tiles[lolPos + j].isVisible = true;
                tiles[lolPos - j].isVisible = true;
            }
        }

        //fourth
        for (int i = 3; i > -4; i -= 6)
        {
            int lolPos = pos + (i * columns);
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                tiles[lolPos + j].isVisible = true;
                tiles[lolPos - j].isVisible = true;
            }
        }

        //fifth
        for (int i = 4; i > -5; i -= 8)
        {
            int lolPos = pos + (i * columns);
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                tiles[lolPos + j].isVisible = true;
                tiles[lolPos - j].isVisible = true;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 5; i > -6; i -= 10)
        {
            int lolPos = pos + (i * columns);
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                tiles[lolPos + j].isVisible = true;
                tiles[lolPos - j].isVisible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

So I made a catch block, in case the error happens my progam does not crash.

```
            try
            {
                lightUp(player);
            }
            catch { }
```

But, I am still getting `IndexOutOfRange` exceptions. They get not trapped by the `catch` block.
Why is that?

EDIT:
Thanks for all the answers. Thought, the problem does not lie in the debug mode options.
I figured out that this only happens **when the program starts.** I tested if I just walk to "out of range" (The void lights-up the tiles near the player), the catch block does actually work. But not when I start my program.(The position of the player is random, if it is near the side of the left screen, the exception happens at startup.)

ANOTHER EDIT: I fixed the "magic numbers"(not bellow zero and not over the maximum),
and that will always work, no matter what happens to it.

Comment: You mean exception thrown out of try catch ? Hard to believe

Comment: OK, stupid question - are you in debug mode? Because sometimes Visual Studio is configured to stop at all exceptions, even before the `catch` block.

Comment: I would strongly recommend changing the code - these are really bad habbits. Try-catch is supposed to catch exceptions, that don't depend on you. OutOfRange exception is absolutely unacceptable, whether you'll catch it or not.

Comment: That doesn't seem likely - which leads me to wonder if you're either mis-reading the exception (which line does the exception stack trace indicate is the problem?) or the minified sample you've pasted here is not an accurate representation. One thing to note - you shouldn't just swallow and lose exceptions, certainly not with a catch-all catch like that. What about OutOfMemory, ThreadAborted, etc, etc? Do it right and fix the bad code. An OutOfRange should never be unexpected...

Comment: Can u add an exception variable to catch block to see if this makes a difference?

Comment: are you sure you have posted your code as it is. I suspect you are missing something.

Comment: With the posted code the exception will be caught. Try to describe what does (not) happen in more detail.

Comment: Please show where the OutOfRange exception is finally caught.  Why are you not catching the actual exception and writing it out in debug?

Comment: On a separate note, you should really google about magic numbers in programming. No offense, but that's some really ugly code and fixing the magic numbers would at least be a start. I would hate to have to maintain that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to try this one:

```
  public void lightUp(int pos)
{
    int loopcounter = -2;
    int jcount = 8;
    int stepcount=1;
    int stepcountReflected=0;
    try
    {
        for (int x = 1; x > -6; x--)
            {
                if (x == 1)
                {
                    stepcountReflected=0.5*stepcount;
                }
                else
                {
                    stepcountReflected = stepcount;
                }
                for (int i = stepcount; i > loopcounter; i =- (2 * stepcountReflected))
                {
                    int lolPos = pos + (i * columns);
                    for (int j = 0; j < jcount; j++)
                    {
                        tiles[lolPos + j].isVisible = true;
                        tiles[lolPos - j].isVisible = true;

                    }
                }
                loopcounter = loopcounter - 1;
                jcount = jcount - 1;
            }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // do what yo need to do here
    }


}
```

Currently you are attempting to catch exception outside of your sub/function and that is why you are not getting solid error description.
When you put none specific "Exception" instead of very specialized "StackOverflowException" you will see what and where is giving you headache.
Adding recorded log of line by line activity may help you as well but this is way outside of your question, just what I would do.

Comment: Okay this is not relevant anymore... But thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Check in VS whether you don't have the option to break on exceptions checked (keyboard shortcut: `ctrl+d, e`):

http://truncatedcodr.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/visual-studiodebugexceptions/

The row "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" is relevant here.

Answer (score -1):

Two things beside the exception problem I can see:

1. There is too much code in that method. It will be hard to test and if it fails, hard to figure out why - which is what you are seeing now.
2. The code looks like c/p with a few corrections, so you would properly be better of abstracting so it. This will make it easier to change later, and less code. Less code is almost always good.

The problem you are facing is that you have to specifiy what error you want to catch, and do the necessary error handling. It is customary to not catch all exception(Exception class) because that will make it even harder to debug. It is evil!

Comment: Good points, but all off-topic.